# Java regex for word with dot

Tags: java, regex

I need to a regex to validate a string like `"foo.com"`. A word which contains a dot. I have tried several but could not get it work.

The patterns I have tried:

1. `(\\w+\\.)`
2. `(\\w+.)`
3. `(\\w.)`
4. `(\\W+\\.)`

Can some one please help me one this.

Thanks,

Comment: use it like `([\w.]+)`.............

Comment: Pranav, thanks that solved my problem

Comment: try using https://regex101.com/

Comment: @PranavCBalan That doesn't require a dot.

Comment: @shmosel :  what you mean?

Comment: @PranavCBalan My understanding is that OP is testing for the presence of a dot, which your regex doesn't do.

Comment: @shmosel :  as per my understanding he needs to match string like `"foo.com"`.... and the regex will match that and user already responded as it working.... If he needs just one dot then he can use `(\\w*\\.\\w*)`

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the duplicated back slashes are actually for string escaping and not really part of the regex? This is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 7):

Use regex with [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

```
([\\w.]+)
```

If you just want to contain single `.` then use

```
(\\w+\\.\\w+)
```

In case you want multiple `.` which is not adjacent then use

```
(\\w+(?:\\.\\w+)+)
```

Comment: another variant on this great answer (thanks!), that only allows lowercase and digits as part of the word: `^([a-z0-9]+(?:[.][a-z0-9]+)+)$`

Comment: NOTE: I had to modify it a little bit, to allow a string with no `.` characters, which is valid for my use case, e.g. the word `test` should be valid. new pattern: `^([a-z0-9]+(?:[.][a-z0-9]+)*)$`

Answer (score 3):

To validate a string that contains exactly one dot and at least two letters around use match for

```
\w+\.\w+
```

which in Java is denoted as

```
\\w+\\.\\w+
```

Answer (score 2):

This regex works: 
[\w\[.\]\\]+

Tested for following combinations:
foo.com
foo.co.in
foo...
..foo

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question like, you need a regex to match a word which has a single dot in-between the word (not first or last).

Then below regex will satisfy your need.

```
^\\w+\\.\\w+$
```